# Allow permission to some page cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create some permission to my site in cakephp but not works permission check.
I want only for example allow only the page `add` the other page like `index` or `register` doesn't have access.

This is my AppController component

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login', 'admin'=>false),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'logout'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller'=>'shows', 'action'=>'index'),
            'authError' => 'Questa risorsa non sembra appartenere al tuo account, oppure non hai eseguito l\'accesso',
            'autoRedirect' => false,
            'authorize' => array(
                'Controller',
                'Actions' => array(
                    'actionPath' => 'controllers'
                )
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

And this is the beforeFilter inside UserController:

```
public function beforeFilter () {
   parent::beforeFilter();  
   $this->Auth->deny('*'); //I have also tried $this->Auth->deny();
   $this->Auth->allow('register');
}
```

Why I can access to the other pages? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Cakephp book: By default all actions require authorization. However, after making actions public, you want to revoke the public access. You can do so using AuthComponent::deny(): 
What you are doing with deny is probably only because of lack of knowledge how Auth works. Please check this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html 
$this->Auth->deny(); // Will remove all the actions.

Comment: I I add $this->Auth->deny('index'); single uer can access to that page, then not works again

Answer (score 0):

You should use Acl Component of cakephp which gives you a perfect scenario in which you can decide for which page you should give permission and which not

Read this:-
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html

and then invoke component in AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Acl'
```

}

Comment: Acl is for other purpose, I know that with Auth allow you can manage this access without Acl